# Android: build android application to check app is running at emulator or real device

Tags: android

We need to develop android basic app which will detect the device is real or emulator and behave accordingly. But did not found sample code or process to detect this thing actually. Please suggest me somebody to resolve this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can check *Build.PRODUCT*

```
"google_sdk".equals(Build.PRODUCT);
```

Comment: I would recommend this:
 Build.PRODUCT.startsWith("google_sdk")

there are other strings for x86 and mips, so this seems to me more safe.

Answer (score 0):

The IMEI on the emulator is "00000000000000". Just check in your app if the IMEI equals the systems IMEI.